# What is a less offensive synonym for "retarded"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, politeness

I occasionally use "retarded" when chastising myself or other friends. I know it's not Politically Correct, but am I only allowed to say stupid? How long before we can't say that anymore?

Other words like "ignorant" don't work well because well, I don't like that word because it's misunderstood (even though it works well for how I say retarded . . for me it's like if you don't know something you should know).

Comment: How about you give us an example sentence?

Comment: Maybe the least offensive thing to do would be to not chastise people (yourself or otherwise) on the basis of their perceived mental adeptness. Sugarcoating an offensive idea doesn't make the idea of it less offensive.

Comment: Yes, good edit on the question Jeff changing it from pc to "less offensive" even though with 101 rep you shouldn't be able to do that. :) I know the PC version . . even though "developmentally disabled" doesn't sound all that great either.

Comment: Somebody needs to rephrase the title of this question to, say: What is a better way to say, "Man, I'm so retarded". Too many people are misunderstanding the question as is.

Comment: @nohat True, negative thoughts swirling in my head are bad news but sometimes they get free and about the best I can do is say something in a nicer way. Beside, I don't think it's all that bad to say (to myself or someone else) that a mistake was made because I didn't think the problem though or even just pay attention.

Comment: @nohat That's such a retarded comment you made. ;)

Comment: @nohat: I couldn't disagree more. Sugarcoating by definition makes an offensive idea less offensive. Does anyone else remember the quip about a fellow so skillful with words that he could tell you to go to hell in such a way that you actually looked forward to the trip?

Comment: I've seen "tard" used. Is this a tad less offensive than "retard"?

Comment: Frankly, it's probably a lost cause at this point. Might as well just use "retarded". [Idiot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiot#Disability) was a medical term. As was [moron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moron_(psychology)), [imbecile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbecile), [cretin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretinism), and [feeble-minded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feeble-minded). These are pejoratives because they're unpleasant things to be and to be around. Since every new term eventually becomes non-PC, we might as well accept that instead of gradually adding more synonyms.

Comment: "Mentally challenged" works pretty well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are several examples:

**When referring to someone who has mental retardation**

Speaking as someone with a few years of experience working with people with developmental disabilities the current politically correct term is what I just used.

"They are retarded" becomes "They are people with developmental disabilities.".

**When referring to myself**

"God, I'm so retarded" becomes "God, I'm so silly".

Other possibilities include: foolish, dumb, and stupid.

**When directing it *at* someone**

"WTF, are you retarded?" becomes "What were you thinking?"

"That was a retarded thing to do" becomes "That was an ill conceived thing to do"

Comment: Again, I don't think that's what he's asking. He wants an inoffensive pejorative to use on himself when the occasion demands it.

Comment: @mmyers: sigh... Jeff's edit makes it clearer

Comment: Yeah, at first the question was "What is the PC version" but that was reta..., damn it can we get to the bottom of this! And while were at it what can I say instead of "damn it" and still make it sound funny?

Comment: I find it interesting that you would rephrase "retarded" but not "God". Why is one more offensive than the other?

Comment: @mmyers: That's completely tangential to this question.

Comment: So pretty soon "thinking" will become an insult?!?

Comment: @mmyers, Because using *retarded* as an insult takes a sideswipe at people who are developmentally disabled, which is *not cool*. Using *God* as an intensifier may upset some people, but it's no insult. Also, I don't care much about offending the powerful. It's the disenfranchised who need protection.

Comment: "That was an ill conceived thing to do" is a bit far from the original in register, I think.  "Foolish" would fit better than "ill conceived", IMO -- though if I were to use the latter I would hyphenate it (not that it's likely to be written...).

Comment: Also I would not say "They are people with developmental disabilities" (which simply substitutes "retarded" with the phrase) but rather "They have developmental disabilities" which describes the people.  Cf. "They have red hair" vs. "They are red-haired people".

Answer (score 59):

Perhaps you could carry around with you this list of 125,000 Shakespearean insults, and just rattle one of those off, like: **I'm such a bootless, beetle-headed boor-pig** and call your friend a **droning, doghearted bladder**.

http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/Shakespearean_Insults.html

Comment: Wow, this answer really came from behind! Earlier today this was at the bottom with no votes. But I like it . . . reminds me of what Homer Simpson did because he didn't want to put money into the swear jar. Trouble is, I'd need to be way more creative than I am and then I'd have to explain the creativity to the person I was just trying to call a <insert the answer here>.

Comment: @cori: I up-voted it again for you. Now, could somebody please up-vote it again, for me?

Comment: @tooshel No, see, that's the beauty of obscure insults: you *don't* have to explain! Either the victim gets the meaning right away, or they don't and think you complimented them, avoiding an escalation entirely

Answer (score 15):

Here are some nice ones. Some may be more familiar, depending on your background:

- *ass* (This is not offensive! "Don't be such an ass!")
- *blockhead* (I especially like this one! Include all the other *-head*'s: *bonehead*, *meathead*, *thickhead*, etc. "That bloke's a real blockhead!")
- *buffoon* (My brother's favorite! "You're an empty-headed buffoon!")
- *dolt* (I like how heavy and final this sounds.)
- *dullard* (Love this one! "Gosh, Jimi, you're a dullard!")
- *dumbo*
- *dummy*
- *dunce* (This is a nice, friendly term!)
- *dunderhead* (An elderly friend's favorite. It's so funny when she uses it. "Dunderheads!")
- *fool* (Not in my dictionary!)
- *idiot* (I'm in the minority that consider this word slightly offensive and hurtful.)
- *ignoramus* ("Stupid ignoramus of the highest order!")
- *klutz*
- *moron* (Way less offensive in the US but certainly not my favorite for friendly rebuttals.)
- *nitwit* (There's also *dimwit*)
- *nincompoop* (Got this a couple decades ago and loved it. "Scallywags and nincompoops!")
- *ninny* ("Ninnies and *idjits*, all of them!")
- *oaf*  ("Shut up, you oaf!")
- *peabrain* (Don't forget the other *-brain*'s e.g. *lamebrain*!)

I have only included nouns in the above lists. Adjectives abound and it would take ages to list all my favorites! Feel free to also use custom-made sentences. One that I find more humorous is:

- "Dude, your *brain* is full of *sawdust*!"

(A friend said this to me many years ago, and while I was mad then, I laugh now every time I recall the incident.)

*NB: In my mind, all these examples are used in a friendly context, so I hope no one is offended!*

Comment: ...Okay. I agree that "ass" can be used playfully, but it's not where I'm from. Even if you said it lightly, it would result in hurt feelings half the time. That one really depends on how you were raised/ the people you hung out with as a teenager...Just my two cents...

Comment: @kitukwfyer: I was just trying to create a comprehensive list. Here in the US, *ass* is not common. That's why it would probably be more offensive than *retarded*, for instance. I myself don't use the word, but I grew up reading Enid Blyton's *Famous Five*, a children's series, where *ass* was freely used among the Five!

Comment: and, by the way, Enid Blyton was a British author.

Comment: Okay. Like I said, that was just my two cents. I didn't consider that it might be a not big deal in Britain. Like you said, though, it kind of is in the good old US of A. :)

Comment: Out of that list I use *idiot*, *fool* and *nincompoop*, the latter being particularly effective.  How is *fool* not in your dictionary?  Such a common word, most little kids would know it here.

Comment: @Orbling: I used "Not in my dictionary" idiomatically to mean "I don't use the word"!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Oh I see! That makes considerably more sense for a man of your lexiographic talents. ;-)

Comment: *Ass*? In Britain? *Arse*, surely.

Comment: In the UK you can add 'joey' (need to have been a UK kid in the 70s) or 'window licker' (slightly more offensive)

Comment: Seeing "moron" on the list brings Bugs Bunny's exclamation "What a maroon!" to mind.

Comment: The Famous Five's "ass" -- and as used in the first example in the answer -- means "donkey", a stupid, ornery animal.

Comment: The "sawdust" one reminds me of the "glue" variant: "Dude, you've got glue for brains!"

Comment: Also, why isn't "bozo" on the list?

Answer (score 9):

The problem with "retarded" (and equivalently "developmental disabilities") is that it puts lack of professional judgement from someone who should have known better into the same category as people who act their "normal" self.

So to keep alternatives to the facts without underhanded remarks, I'd propose

> That was a bad idea.
>
> Whoops, didn't think of that one!
>
> I should cut down on the booze/drugs! [applicability dependent of workplace humor/ethic]

Or the `English Gentleman` version:

> Dear programmer, your lack of professional judgement in circumventing the quality assurance process lead to an unfortunate incident, delivering a non-optimal product to the customer. You should be ashamed of yourself, since even a trained dog could follow the process better than you.

(With apologies to all dogs on the stackexchange.)

So be creative! There is no need to try to connect people's weaknesses with what you perceive negatively of others.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to use "idiot(ic)." That was originally an actual, medical term for developmentally disabled people. It's out of official use, though, so it's as safe as "stupid" is at any rate.

Comment: @cindi: The Irish, like the British, have a long history of self-deprecation and indeed belittlement of each other.  It is very much part of the culture and only a few rare people find genuine offence in it when said light-heartedly.

Answer (score 6):

Here in the UK we use 'thick' (as sh1t, as mince, as two short planks ...)

Its a useful catch-all that is equally at home amongst teachers referring to pupils and stroppy (US - ratty) software engineers talking about end users or indeed support desk personnel. It can be as offensive or as gently teasing as the user intends.

Comment: Can we not use the word 'shit' on this site?

Comment: Erm I think you did, a couple of months ago and it looks like the censors have let it stand. Personally I prefer to leet up my profanity in case my kids see it when they're older ...

Comment: @5arx - I'd honestly be way more embarrased if my kids caught me using leet.

Comment: P4h! Wh47'5 wr0n9 w17h l33t?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer variations on "What are/were you smoking?"

Comment: Oh yeah, I use this one kind of a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think you should use whatever word you feel like using at the time.

People ***do not*** have the right to go through life without being offended.

Politically correct or not, say what you feel; to cover your feelings with false diplomacy is a far greater sin of dishonesty.

It is not a profanity and a regular English word - when you are chastising people you intend it to be derogatory.  Particularly between friends, such comments are a regular part of life and are meant as teasing commentary only, everyone knows that.

Of course, with freedom of speech comes causation and if you are calling random children in the street retards, then you can probably expect retribution of some sort.  To quote a TV show I am fond of: *"talk bollocks, expect pain"*.

Comment: @TRiG: He was talking about talking directly to other people.  Why would using the word *idiot* be fine, but *retarded* not.  *idiot* has had medical meaning at times, as has *retarded*, both are common words that can be used lightly or strongly depending on context.  You should note that my last paragraph mitigates against encouraging insulting, as I say that you reap what you sow - if you go about insulting people, then retribution can be expected.  Most insults can have wider scope than the immediate recipient, the overly sensitive will always be offended.

Comment: [Comment deleted. If you want your comment to stay up, then leave out the personal attacks. — Kosmonaut]

Comment: @TRiG: As I said in my post, no one has a right to not be offended.  Everyone gets used to being insulted as part of growing up, a good deal of humour tends to revolve around it.  People just have to roll with it, some old saying about sticks and stones comes to mind.  Anyhow, you have a right to your opinion, however impolitely phrased, it obviously does not coincide with mine on this matter, so we had better drop it.

Comment: @Orbling. People do have some sort of right (not in law, of course, but in morals), not to be used as an insult directed at someone else. http://kateharding.net/comments-policy/

Comment: @TRiG: Out of interest, what has that comments policy got to do with stack exchange, pile of cack that it is?

Comment: @Orbling. It's the Shapely Prose comments policy, and, as you imply, does not apply here. But I thought you might be interested in its reasoning.

Comment: @TRiG: It was interesting, some good points, some biased, some awful.  Though I thought it showed a highly megalomaniac, "I am the law" style of thought process.  I'm no fan of the rude, profanity-laden mode she uses; feels like it is done for effect.

Comment: @Orbling. She is the law. It's her website.

Comment: @TRiG: Yeah I know, so does everyone else - the pissy attitude and constant foul-mouthed, dismissive reminders are rather redundant.

Comment: @Orbling. People do know that, but they don't respect it. Shapely Prose was heavily moderated. One of the mods created a tumblr blog of the most offensive comments from entitled arseholes who think everyone should listen to their mansplaning. A little reminder of who's boss does was not out of place.

Comment: @TRiG: Well everyone is entitled to an opinion.  As someone who is not all that far off double my ideal body weight, her "fat acceptance" and various supporting arguments as to why fat is not bad, constructed from cherry-picked papers and a somewhat delusional outlook I find very offensive.  But she is entitled to her opinion, she does cause harm to others by peddling it though.

Comment: @TRiG: So... You *do care about offending...other people standing by*, huh? In that case perhaps you could have avoided gratuitous swearing in your first comment here. I swear like a trooper myself in other contexts, and I've no problem *discussing* profanity on EL&U. But your usage has no significant justification, so I'm afraid I find it offensive in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, There is a very clear distinction between words that dehumanise segments of the population, and words that people don't like. I'm perfectly comfortable with profanity, and I **strongly resent** seeing the two classes of words treated the same. Orbling seemed to think that dehumanising language was *less* offensive than profanity. In this he is absolutely, entirely, irrevocably **wrong**. My use of profanity, in this context, was deliberatly used to make that point. I think that justification is sufficient, whatever you think of its significance.

Comment: @TRiG: Your opinion is your own, please do not read wrong and right in to factless argument.  Particularly when you end by stating the opinion of others has no significance.  Such arrogance is unbecoming.

Comment: @Orbling. Thank you for clarifying that you do in fact think that dehumanising language is less offensive than profanity. I previously said only that it *seemed* to me that you thought that. It's nice to be clear. It's nice to know who the enablers of oppression are. It means I can avoid them.

Comment: @TRiG: Are you using your own personal definition of *offending*, within which I can't be offended by your gratuitous profanity because *you* don't think that counts as offensive? You can argue meaningfully about your right to hold whatever views you like, and to express them however you like. But you can't meaningfully argue about whether **I** am offended or not, so long as we're still basically using English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, My reply to you never mentioned offence. I try, usually, to avoid offending people, but that's not an overriding consideration. I never said that profanity wasn't offensive. I just said I felt I had a justified reason for giving that offence. Offensive words matter. Hurtful words matter more. Confusing the two categories, as Orbling does, is both hurtful and offensive. I felt that was an important point to make, and I felt that the clearest way to make that point was to use profanity. I'm sorry that this offended you, but I'm not going to apologise. What I was saying mattered.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, In addition, I note that at The Slacktiverse, they acknowledge that strong profanity can be triggering for some people, giving them flashbacks to violent or uncomfortable times. Trigger warnings for profanity are recommended. I should probably have used one myself. But since you say you're happy with profanity in other contexts, I imagine this wasn't your problem. To anyone who was triggered, I apologise for not including a warning.

Comment: @TRiG: I fail to see how the substance of your first comment required that fourth word to be present, so I can only assume you used it for emphasis or humour, if not directly for its potential 'shock value'. I'm not *overly* worked up, so there's no real need to apologise. But since you have, thank you. Nevertheless, EL&U isn't really a chat forum, so I think a more measured tone is appropriate here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Emphasis, definitely. Shock, perhaps. Orbling said something **extremely offensive** and **completely wrong**, namely that dehumanizing language is okay, but profanity isn't. This is the viewpoint of the oppressor, who isn't remotely bothered by the pain of the oppressed. A strong response was required. I might say *fuck* to any oppressor. Or I might not. Probably not, in the "professional" context of this site. Here, though, that word was actually required. Read the first commend again. There was no way for me to fully make my point without using that word. (Continued)

Comment: (... continued). @Orbling was not just playing the role of the oppressor dismissing the concerns of the oppressed. He was doing so specifically by saing that oppressive language mattered less than profanity. In that circumstance, profanity in response was, I think, actually required. I'm trying to fight the good fight here. I'll use any weapon at my disposal.

Comment: @TRiG: An oppressor...  Not sure I have been called that before.  Obviously I would have you killed for such a remark, but my minions are otherwise engaged in other unspeakable evil.

Comment: @TRiG: You think there's profanity and there's dehumanising language, but I don't see a clear distinction. I never heard anyone say *prick* dehumanises men, but I certainly know people (including some men) who think *cunt* dehumanises women. I don't specifically recall it coming up in any conversation, but it wouldn't surprise me to learn that some people think *fuck* 'dehumanises' something they feel is explicitly sanctified by their religion, or at least is too central to the human condition to be bandied about lightly. Whatever - let's just leave it at that, okay?

Comment: @Fumble, It's about the history of the word and the relative power positions of people in society. The literal meaning of the word has little to do with its power to do harm. The word *fuck* is not associated with any specific group of people. Using it as an insult therefore does not dehumanise any group of people. It may still be offensive, but it cannot reasonably be called dehumanising. And cavalierly dismissing the concerns of disenfranchised minority groups as unimportant is certainly activity which enables oppression; such activity is therefore in itself oppressive. Do I make sense?

Comment: Um, people, this discussion is way too long for the main site and is already getting auto-flagged by the system. Please take any further comments to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage).

Answer (score 4):

Cant help adding James May's eminently english way of saying "stupid"  to this list.

> "What a **Pillock**"

He has me in splits everytime he says that!

Comment: +1 *pillock* is particularly good, it's offensive, but in a light way.  Usually used for someone who has done something stupid, as opposed to is stupid.

Comment: @5arx - I think pillock is more a one off thing = 
you pillock. May is a bit of a t__t. But using the standard unit of t__t he is only about 100milli-Clarksons

Comment: @mgb - I think that individually and as a collective that trio display too many dislikable traits for one word to sum them up. But, I concur with 't__t' and also offer, variously 'prick', 'tosser', 'a---hole' (the English version with three dashes after the 'a' as they're v. English), 'wazzock', 'dick', the American 'douche' and 'nob' as supplementaries.

Comment: In modern english we now say they are "a bunch of clarksons" or a "complete clarkson"

Answer (score 3):

I prefer "silly". I don't *think* you can offend anyone with that, although strictly speaking it might not be correct usage.

Comment: I think the intent here is to say "someone who can't figure something out because there is something fundamentally, perhaps genetically, wrong with them". And er.. silly isn't that.

Comment: Someone please vote this question back up, I can't anymore because of a technical rule in the website, waited to long. I feel so silly.

Comment: @Jeff: I use "silly" all the time as a "less offensive synonym for retarded"

Comment: @Jeff: In the sense in which the question uses it, "retarded" does not necessarily refer to any underlying disability -- just something temporary. I believe "silly" is acceptable for a temporary bout of mild insanity, yes?

Comment: um, "silly" sounds like something my parent's generation would say, has about the same register as "corny", I think the person wants to have a term he can say to someone when then stick their hand in a toaster: "man, you are so _____". but "silly" doesn't get it.

Comment: I'm with Edward on this one, silly is okay but only if I'm talking to a 6 year old girl.

Comment: This is an affront to silliness, shower the infidel with unicorn droppings!

Answer (score 3):

(Feel free to delete this if people feel it's inappropriate, it's included purely for linguistic reasons - no offense intended.)

The UK charity for people with cerebral palsy was known as the "Spastic Society" - this resulted in a lot of cruel children in the 70s and 80s referring to their less adroit friends as "spastics".

The charity finally decided that they had enough and renamed themselves as "[SCOPE](http://www.scope.org.uk/)" - apparently children now greet failed sporting achievements with "you scope!"

Comment: I remember Ricky Gervais doing a sketch on this very point. :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Slow* fits quite well in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

"Blonde" may be offensive to blondes, but not nearly so likely to get you in trouble as "retarded."  "Stupid" is probably your safest bet -- I like "pants-on-the-head stupid" for emphasis and variety.

Comment: When people use "blonde" in this sense, I usually think they're stupid. But that might be because I'm a blonde. :) Plus, the embarrassed apologies once they realize the slip are always awkward and a little annoying.

Comment: Yes, I would avoid saying, "that's so blonde" mostly because it's just passé, and too easy, a bit below the belt.

Answer (score 2):

The Australian gentle insult of choice would be **dickhead**. If you call someone a dickhead, you are probably laughing at their stupidity; it's not a word you would use when angry...

Comment: ...In the US, this isn't gentle at all...Just warning you in case you ever come to visit. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In this, as in many things, I prefer to go the route of metaphor, however twisted:

"You have less sense than the Good Lord gave a common cabbage."

"No more brains than a squashed frog."

"Compares unfavorably to the competence of a trained monkey."

"Sorry, delete that - I was just having a brain fart."

"Must have slept in the day God was handing out brains..."

"If stupidity was money, Bill Gates would have nuthin' on you..."

"Fewer brain cells than an Amoeba."

"Going for Gold in the stupidity Olympics..."

"Can't count beyond 10 without taking off his shoes..."

...etc...

Oops! I see that the original question was looking for politeness or "less offensiveness". Well, presumably we're talking with friends who know when our tongue is in our cheek...

Answer (score 2):

Lobotomous twit.

Anyone likely to be offended won't get it. ;)

Comment: Brilliant! May I add that to my list of explicit insults to one day use?

Answer (score 1):

Have completed a draft of an article for submission to a magazine. Used the R-word, and realized that it's no longer P.C. The MSWORD thesaurus came up with nuthin. The comments were interesting. I have decided to go with "really-dumb".
Less is more.

Answer (score 1):

"Dense" is a nice softer alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been partial to chucklehead, knucklehead, and asshat.

Answer (score 1):

The Irish used to refer to retarded people as **innocents** (maybe they still do, in Ireland), though that hardly would retain the same connotation if used as the OP is asking but I just thought I'd mention it because I think it's very sweet. The most **un**offensive way of saying it as ever there has been, IMHO, and not too much of a mouth-ful (as *developmentally disabled* tends to be).

Personnally, I like to go with **dip-shitzu**

Answer (score 1):

What about "Nutter"..??      
Isn't that also a British term...implying "insane"?
I know it doesn't have the same association as "retarded" since that is meant as "stupid"...which of course, is not what "retarded" means.  "Slow" is more accurate.  That doesn't mean I like it; I have seen many speak abusively to others using that term as well...as an example, parents stating that one of their children is "slow" *in the child's presence*!!

I remember when "develomentally disabled" came into vogue; later it was re-worked and "developmentally delayed" became the more accepted phrase.  That's a fairly diplomatic way of saying "slow".

Also, I don't have any issues around the needs for 'softer' language; that may be a result of having lived 25+ years in a small city with a *large* university.  Diplomacy is an important -- and underrated -- tool for effective communication!  That, I believe, is why residents of the U.K. often come up with the most creative -- and humorous -- long insulting sentences; they understand the need for diplomacy better than many residents of the U.S.

There's my .10  (.02 adjusted for long-term inflation ;)