# More eloquent word or phrase

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a less offensive synonym for “retarded”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570/what-is-a-less-offensive-synonym-for-retarded)

Can anyone please furnish me with a word, or short phrase, that would eloquently describe a person who has never had to countenance failure, one who is so self satisfied and self assured with himself that he has no humility?
I am afraid that any words like "super smug prig" (my own personal favorite) would be invalid in the context of an academic essay.

Comment: some punctuation would probably be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a less offensive synonym for "retarded"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570/). Before you say "no-no-no", please do read the top answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One adjective for this is "cocksure." Another is "hubristic."

Comment: hubristic is real good, have to mull it over

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact match, but *vainglorious* comes to mind:

> vainglory: excessive or ostentatious pride especially in one's achievements ( http://merriam-websterscollegiate.com/dictionary/vainglory )

And by following a few links on that page: *overweening* ( http://merriam-websterscollegiate.com/dictionary/overweening ). I've not actually seen this one used personally, but I do like the fact that it sounds like "wieny/weeny" ( => wiener => sausage => slang for penis )

Comment: vainglorious is wonderful but maybe not for this guy, d'oh!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this covers the entire spectrum of what you're looking for, but perhaps "golden boy" or "golden child" or "fortunate son" could be used to cover the "always successful, never failed" part, at least.

Comment: thanks but not applicable