# An inoffensive word for "stupid"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

In my native language, there is a word that has a meaning similar to *stupid*, but it is friendly and usually used for a close friend or loved one. It even helps the target people to feel happy in some cases, especially romantic situation where the "stupidity" stems from a cute action or misunderstanding.

Is there any similar word in English?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570/what-is-a-less-offensive-synonym-for-retarded

Comment: @JasperLoy For example, when a friend tells me that he don't know what a girl he is in love is thinking, but you are fully understanding the situation, I may say this in my language: "You are such a "stupid" guy". That sentence has no offensive mean, but he knows that he is in a funny situation in others' eyes.

Comment: I usually get called "dummy" ;)

Comment: I think this is a good example of a question that should include the source language and word, and be tagged `translation`.  I would allow it.

Comment: Cute action or misunderstanding maybe silly, it's inoffensive because it's kind of childish and would probably make people laugh.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume OP is really looking for a word meaning *"stupid"*, but with positive connotations (along the lines of *"cuddly"* for *"fat"*, and maybe *"homely"* for *"ugly"*).

Teachers, for example, may speak of [less able](http://www.strath.ac.uk/media/faculties/hass/scilt/slr/issues/18/18_bremner.pdf) students. But that's just because sometimes they can't avoid referring to such pupils (and it would be unprofessional to call them "stupid").

In normal conversational contexts, any reference to someone's lack of intelligence is likely to be seen as impolite and/or hurtful, so it's probably best avoided unless you *intend* to be disparaging.

OP might feasibly get away with **uncomplicated**, (or perhaps *slow, simple, naive*), but generally speaking such terms will be recognised for what they are (euphemisms) - so again, best avoided.

---

One common approach is to "soften" the label with humour. For example, you can say someone's...

> [one sandwich short of a picnic](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/one-sandwich-short-of-a-picnic.html) *(a few clowns short of a circus, etc.)*
>
> [not playing with a full deck](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/260000.html) *(of cards, similar construction to above)*
>
> [thick as a brick](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thick_as_a_brick) *(...two short planks, ...shit, etc.)*

EDIT: Following OP's later comment, it's apparent he wants a friendly/affectionate term by which to address his friend, who's showing a lack of understanding *in some particular context*. That's not really the same thing as trying to explain to others that your friend is significantly less intelligent than the average.

I suggest suitable phrasing in OP's context would be something slightly "whimsical", such as...

> "Oh, you're such a [ninny / noodle / nincompoop / etc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ninny)! Anyone can see she's madly in love with you!"

Comment: I really like _noodle_. It's even listed in my dictionary as _informal: a stupid or silly person_, yet it sounds like it would be "soft on the ego" – almost affectionate, even.

Comment: You think of *cuddly* as related to *pudgy*?   Really?  I’ve never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @tchrist: I personally would never admit to scanning the Lonely Hearts section in newspapers - but I have a friend who does, and he assures me that women there describe themselves as *cuddly and vivacious* when they mean *fat slag*.

Answer (score 17):

"silly," "goof," or "dork" all work in casual/flirtatious conversation.

Comment: None of these mean stupid, or even close to it...

Comment: @NominSim maybe not without context, but i think any of those words implies the same thing that "stupid" (or "stupid guy") does in the OP's follow-up comment. No?

Comment: I agree that they could be used in a casual/flirtatious conversation, however the OP seems to be looking specifically for a way to tell the person they are stupid. Considering from the comments that the "stupid" person in question is already showing a lack of understanding of social conventions, they may not get the implication. If you add something like _naive_ to your answer I would be more than happy to switch my vote. :)

Comment: @NominSim: `silly` does, at least so says the dictionary... `Naïve` on the other hand is more "credulous" than "stupid".

Comment: @nico  _Naive_ having or showing a lack of experience, judgment. That seems to be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @NominSim: Hmmmm... in my mind, the question refers more to a situation in which I would use *silly*. Maybe the OP should give an example...

Comment: @nico They did in the comments of the question, "silly" works well too I suppose.

Comment: @NominSim: I may not call these synonyms for "stupid", either, but I still think there is plenty of overlap in certain contexts. E.g., I can think of circumstances where _"That was a stupid thing to say"_ and _"That was a silly thing to say"_ could both be used.  Same for, _"Don't be stupid!"_ vs. _"Don't be a goof!"_; or, _"That makes you look stupid"_ vs. _"That makes you look like a dork."_

Comment: @NominSim When a direct translation is impossible, one is left with interpretation. Charles's answers seem quite legitimate, to me (and to many others given the vote count). Someone may be called a *goof* because he is stupid in regards to women; the *stupid* part is understood from context but the hearer understands the affection attached because of the different word choice.

Answer (score 16):

I am morally obligated to nominate my usual term for the purpose, [*adorkable*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Adorkable) (a portmanteau of *adorable* and *dorky*).

Calling someone a *goofball* is similar and less neologistic, if a bit antiquated.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used `adorkable`. I now feel obliged to use it next time my SO does something adorkable ;)

Comment: “doofus” may be similar.

Answer (score 16):

A word that is often used in this context in British English is ***dope*** or ***dopey*** e.g. 'you dopey old thing!' - affectionate but not too unkind.

Comment: Came here to offer this!

Answer (score 10):

I'd go for the simple "daft".

I've never once, that I recall, known anybody say or take it as offensive or insulting.  It's very common too.

> Don't be daft!  She clearly loves you.
>
> Oh, you're such a dafty!  How can you not see that?
>
> Dave?  He's as daft as a ship's cat!

Answer (score 7):

In that situation, you could use almost anything.

I can imagine saying something like "Oh, you *mushroom!*" or something similarly nonsensical.

Answer (score 6):

It is not used that much by English speakers these days, but the word that fits best (especially for the romantic scenario as in *fool for love* or *lovefool*) is probably [*fool*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foolishness) which means a person who lacks wisdom as opposed to one who lacks intelligence.

Comment: Really? I think _fool_ is offensive if I tell my girlfriend "Oh, you _fool_!"?

Comment: @W.N. Like many words, _fool_ can be positive or negative depending on the context. When employed in the positive, it is often in a romanticized or nostalgic context. E.g., _I'm a fool for you_, or _an old fool such as I_.

Comment: @W.N., also in regards to the classic fool in the form of a court-jester.

Comment: In English, "stupid" is considered *much* more insulting than "fool".

Answer (score 6):

Said in the right tone and the right context, *numpty* might serve. It is Scottish in origin, and the OED defines the adjective ‘as stupid, foolish, idiotic’. However, the first definition in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=numpty) seems to strike the right note:

> a) Someone who (sometimes unwittingly) by speech or action
>   demonstrates a lack of knowledge or misconception of a particular
>   subject or situation to the amusement of others.
>
> b) A good humoured admonition, a term of endearment
>
> c) A reckless, absent minded or unwise person

Comment: What about *you are such a dork*?

Answer (score 5):

I would use the word naive.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/naive
To me it means, the person is not stupid, he/she is just 'inexperience in the field', or he/she is just 'unsuspecting' or 'credulous'.

Answer (score 3):

I'm hard-pressed to think of a POSITIVE word for "stupid". How could being stupid be a good thing? (Well, it might be good for me for someone else to be stupid, so that I can defeat him in some competition or take advantage of him, but it's not good for him.)

The closest to a postive word that I can think of is "simple". Like you might say, "Yeah, yeah, you have all these complex arguments, but I'm a *simple* guy, it just seems to me that ..." "Simple" is sometimes used when you want to say that another person is being too clever, perhaps making something more complicated than it needs to be, or is trying to fool others by using fancy language to cover up a fallacy.

A common euphemism is "slow". As in, "We'll be offerring tutoring sessions to help the slow students pass this class." When I was in school it was common to talk about the smart kids as "gifted students" and the dumb kids as "slow students". I don't know if these terms are still common.

Another euphemism was that class for less-smart kids were called "special education", and so the kids were called "special".

You could use "silly" or "cute" in some contexts.

But in general, I'd avoid looking for any word that means anything remotely like "stupid" if you're trying to keep a conversation friendly. Maybe there's a word in Spanish that would be perceived in a friendly way, but I don't think there's such a word in English. You can try to make it less offensive by using euphemisms, but it's still an insult.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to someone as *dozy* isn't particularly offensive, nor does it necessarily imply a continued state of being. Instead, it describes them as not being less than attentive, slow at responding to the task at hand or perhaps lazy. Could it be construed as cute? In the context of being slow to catch-on, then certainly, it could be used as a temporary term of endearment. Nevertheless, continued use could be seen as being increasingly offensive.

Answer (score 3):

"Goob".  It hearkens to Goober from the Andy Griffith Show, who was a loveable, yet dim-witted, character.  No one I have ever called this took it offensively.

Answer (score 2):

How about "*duffer*".  It sounds cutesy, and it plays off someone's incompetence in a playful manner.  See listing 2 in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duffer).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer "knucklehead" for endearingly stating someone is stupid.

Answer (score 2):

I've always liked:

- Twerp
- Muppet
- Moomin
- 'Silly Sausage'

Those are mainly Northern English (UK) terms afaik.

Maybe 'Nobby' too, but that's slightly offensive.

Answer (score 1):

In San Francisco for a while people used to say "silly-boy" or "silly-girl," - or "silly-me," quickly, almost as one word. Prefacing with *silly-* or *little-* might take away some of sting. In Spanish, with its infinite degrees of diminutivization, you can make *tonto* become *tontuello*, "little clown" to call someone you're fond of.

There's also *-head*, as in lazyhead or puzzlehead or bonehead ...

Answer (score 1):

The least offensive way to express that someone is a bit slow on the uptake is to call them [*simple*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/simple?s=t).  It’s a lot less negative and judgemental than the rest of them come off sounding.

Just don’t move on to calling them a *simpleton*, because that one’s back in negative territory.

*Simple* also provides for plausible deniability should offence be taken where none is  intended. That’s because although you mean the word in the OED2’s sense **9b** . . .

> - **9.** Deficient in knowledge or learning; characterized by a certain lack of acuteness or quick apprehension: 
>   **a.** of persons or animals 
>    **b.** of mental powers

. . . you can always backpeddle if need be, falling back on gentler senses, such as:

> 1. Free from duplicity, dissimulation, or guile; innocent and harmless; undesigning, honest, open, straightforward.
> 2. Free from, devoid of, pride, ostentation, or display; humble, unpretentious.
> 3. **a.** Free from elaboration or artificiality; artless, unaffected; plain, unadorned. 
>     **b.** Of persons: Free from over-refinement, unsophisticated, unspoiled.

Aren’t those — um, convenient? There are other senses of *simple* that are less complimentary, but having complimentary ones to fall back to in case of social missteps is especially convenient. That way even though  you  might  actually means *simple* as in stupid, you could if pressed fall back to *simple* meaning honest and humble, unpretentious and unsophisticated.

Seems like a win to me — at least if you’re looking to be inoffensive.

Answer (score 1):

Minimally exceptional, is good because it is funny. I first heard George Carlin use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized, if you have a southern accent, you can get by with some outrageous insults by preceding or following it with "bless his/her heart". Here is an example. "He means well, but if his brains was put on the head of a pin, they'd roll around like a marble on a freeway." I don't know if that answers your question, but it sure seems to dilute an awful lot of derogatory or offensive language.

Comment: Note the tag `single-word-requests`.

Comment: @luke blesshisheart?