# How to insult a Tory (or people holding a conservative viewpoint in general)?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, offensive-language

I am writing a contemporary theatre play where one character - a senior businessman - first introduces himself as a not particularly conservative person. Later in the play, his protégé finds that the businessman is in fact deeply conservative and wants to express his anger over the deception. I'm therefore looking for a british word that can insult Tories or conservative persons in general, emphasising that it is the conservativeness that the insulter takes objection of.

I started with "Twit", which might remind of Monty Python's "Upper Class Twit of the Year", but I have the feeling, that this is not a particularly strong insult these days. Since I'm not a native speaker, I have trouble in general estimating the strength of insults.

Comment: American: http://www.fightconservatives.com/Inside-the-Book/Conservative-Insult-Generator.html British: http://www.totalpolitics.com/quotes/?tag=insulting+conservatives&count=42

Comment: Is it contemporary? If it is, then you could use much stronger language (the British middle-classes and higher don't hold back with their insults). "Twit" said between two grown men sounds childish, but in the right context, in the right tone of voice, could work as a way of mocking or ridiculing the businessman's allegiance.

Comment: I forgot to say, yes, it is contemporary. How about strengthening "Twit" to "F**ing twit"?

Comment: Oh, that's good, and "twat" is popular, too. I believe it is much more offensive in the US, but in the UK I'd consider it almost *tame*. You should watch the TV series "In the thick of it". It's on YouTube. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thick_of_It

Comment: @Mari-LouA I wouldn't say that *twit* is childish in British English use, though it is mild enough that most adults wouldn't consider it a swear-word if a child used it. It's mild, though that mildness can imply you are dismissing the target, by not even bothering to insult them more strongly. *Twat* is certainly a bit stronger, nowhere near as strong as *cunt* despite meaning the same thing, but strong enough that there would not be a children's book called *The Twats* while there is one called *The Twits*.

Comment: @JonHanna Agreed that "twit" could be used as a sarcastic device, but the protagonist is enraged by the businessman's deceit, so I would choose much stronger language. The myth that the British upper-classes are always polite and refrain from expressing their disdain explicity, is a false one.

Comment: Agreed on both counts. That said, those who do refrain from expressing disdain through expletives can often be all the more masterful in expressing disdain for that, regardless of class. Then there are people like myself, who use expletives more freely than we probably should, but who refrain from them when we're *really* angry.

Comment: Just popped into my head: "Wanker" I'd say that too while "tosser" is definitely BrEng.

Comment: But aren't these more general purpose insults?

Comment: Yes, but if you preceded them with either "Tory" or "fascist" as suggested by Jon Hanna they would work.

Comment: Wow, what an offensive question. You [froward folly-fallen coxcomb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/579/300)!

Comment: How strong a word are you looking for? The 'N' word (rhymes with 'Yahtzee!') matches the semantics you're looking for (an insult for someone who is conservative). But of course, this is a bit insensitive. I think this question is ill-advised because it welcomes all sorts of similar distasteful questions.

Comment: Isn't "***Tory!***" offensive enough?

Comment: For my play, I am actually interested in a special usecase where N* or Fascist im probably too strong and Tory on its own too weak. But in other contextes (is that the correct plural?), for example between people of a strong left wing opinion, I can see that Tory makes a swearword on its own.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I never noticed this question before. I'm astonished it's survived. How long do you suppose *How to insult a Christian/Muslim/religious Jew (or people holding a theistic viewpoint in general)?* would last?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not long at all, but this question is *political* and not based on religious beliefs, I see no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Wot? So *religious* beliefs are somehow more sacred than political beliefs? Doesn't that leave people like me (who hold that eternal truth is to be found within *actual humanity/humankind*, not *hypothetical gods*) in a somewhat disadvantaged position? That smacks to me of unjustified special privilege. And what about *How to insult a gay rights activist/supporter of disabled people/atheist (or people holding an XXXX viewpoint in general)?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, read the question. I'm writing a theatre play. I don't actually intend to insult someone. I just want it to be realistic.

Comment: @Turion: Apart from the fact that arguably what you're asking for is *writing advice*, that "justification" could equally well apply to any request for "credible ways of insulting [some class of people or their beliefs]". Basically, a POB invitation to ELU users to vent their spleen if they happen not to like that class of people.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, do you actually think that these people will do an internet search before they go and insult someone?

Comment: @Turion: I haven't suggested anything remotely like that. I'm simply making the point (perhaps somewhat obliquely) that every answer (and indeed, most comments) are quite clearly from people who take it as a given that insulting the "conservative" political perspective is a natural, right and proper thing to do. Which attitude would definitely *not* be tolerated on this site if the object of their vitriol were some other target.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I doubly doubt your statement. As for my part, I object to personal insults to members of either political attitude in real life. But I would find a question like mine towards another political party or belief justified in the context of literature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could of course just stick *Tory* in front of a more general insult of whatever degree of forcefulness you desire, from "Tory twit" through "Tory bastard" and "Tory fucker" to "Tory cunt".

If your character leans quite a bit to the left, then they might well abuse the term "fascist" as an insult for a Tory. If your character leant further to the left, they might even earnestly consider your Tory character to be a fascist.

Or you could stack a variety of terms about views more likely to be held by Tories than someone further left, in the opinion of someone on the left, (traditionally at least, some of the following could be said as easily about New Labour); "war-mongering, profiteering, granny-starving, gay-bashing, women-hating, racist fear-mongering, Tory fucker".

Or if it's the 17th Century, you could just use *Tory* (the word is originally an insult).

Edit: Mari-Lou's comment made me think of a more specific and subtler insult, which is "[Disgusted of Tubridge-Wells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disgusted_of_Tunbridge_Wells)".

Comment: Or add something about being a "Daily Telegraph reader" but I wouldn't know how to phrase it. (Top notch answer btw)

Comment: "F*ing profiteering Daily-Telegraph-reading Tory twit!", or something like that. I'm getting there I guess. Maybe I'll leave a footnote for the actors to optionally "upgrade" to "Tory bastard".

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Daily Telegraph reader" can certainly be taken as such an insult, with "Daily Mail reader" being a stronger insult with a stronger degree of credulity and knee-jerk reaction implied; strong enough that even many Conservatives would consider it an insult on its own (not all Tories are so mentally benighted as to think the Daily Mail has anything but the most tenuous connection to reality). You've also made me think of another one to add.

Comment: I'd say rather than having a footnote suggesting actors increase the degree of venom, write at the degree you are aiming at, and let the director choose to tone it down if they think it necessary for their audience. Certainly, I would't be surprised at hearing much stronger language than *bastard* in the theatre.

Answer (score 0):

You could considering using an [insult generator](http://politicalhumor.about.com/library/bl-conservative-insults.htm?insult=719060259).

You could adapt [Eric Heffer's description](http://www.totalpolitics.com/quotes/?tag=Eric+Heffer&count=1) of the Tory government:

> They are nothing else but a load kippers - two-faced, with no guts.

The `two-faced` chiming in with the businessman's earlier attempts at appearing different from what he really is.

Answer (score 0):

How about comparison: He's so far right-wing he makes Margaret Thatcher look like a Liberal.

Answer (score -1):

It's worth pointing out that the word "Tory" is itself often used by opponents of the Conservative party *as* an insult.  I am a Conservative activist in the UK, and I recently discovered that, in their internal polling system, the Labour Party uses the letter "T" to denote "Conservative".  In contrast, in our internal polling system, we use the letter "C" to denote the Conservative Party.  Interestingly, we use the letter "S" - for "socialist" - to denote "Labour" in our system (with "L" meaning Lib Dem), as we have historically considered that to be an insult.

It should be pointed out, however, that many Conservative activists - myself included - *don't* view the word "Tory" as an insulting term, and in fact wear it with pride.

If this seems confusing, it's because the word "Tory" refers to a specific *kind* of conservative ideology in the UK (and North America) which predates the contemporary Conservative Party.  The Conservative Party was formed out of the historical Tory Party by Prime Minister Robert Peel in the 19th Century, and this represented a significant ideological as well as cosmetic change. The "Conservative Party" came to represent a blended ideology which included parts of the ideology of both the historical Tories and the historical Whigs.  As time progressed, this fusion of ideology deepened as two things - Irish nationalism and, later, the rise of socialism - led to more and more supporters of the (historical) Liberal Party (which represented views which today would be - roughly - thought of as right-wing libertarian) joining the Conservatives and thus increasing the "Conservative" commitment to the historically "liberal" values of free markets, capitalism, etc - which the Tory Party had always viewed with some suspicion as vulgar and disruptive to the social order.

However, many of us Conservatives still feel a strong sense of affinity with the historical Tory Party and (to some degree) its ideology, which, among other things, ended child labour, was crucial to the abolition of slavery and emphasises British Unionism, patriotism and the empire - particularly affinity with the "Dominions" of Canada/Australia, etc - which is why the Canadian Conservatives are also called "Tories".

Basically (simplifying **massively**), "Conservative" refers more to the modern, Thatcher/Reagan-style conservatism of free markets, individual liberty and social conservatism in the "family values" American sense.  "Tory", on the other hand, refers more to traditional, British conservatism in the sense of the monarchy, slower social evolution, a hierarchical (but benevolent) social structure, the establishment of the Church of England and the Church of Scotland (technically a "national", rather than "established" church) and (historically) support for British imperialism.  To some degree, many British Conservative/Tory supporters feel an affinity with both identities. Complicating things further, some modern Conservatives will pointedly correct you if you call them Tories, and tell you that they are proud Whigs!

In "class" terms, historically, the Tory Party also represented more the petty aristocracy and middle-class merchants, whereas the Whigs represented more the elite aristocrats and wealthy industrialists, although this see-sawed a lot throughout history and was never anything like that simple.

This is a very brief summation of a very complex issue, which whole books could be written about.  If you are writing fiction, you are *probably* safe to assume that Conservative supporters will refer to themselves as "Conservatives", while their opponents will refer to them as "Tories" as an insult - but be aware that this is a massive simplification.

Comment: I would also add that journalists/reporters will often use the word "Tory", only for the purposes of linguistic variation.  E.g. my local newspaper will write: "Conservative Councillor John Smith..." in one sentence, and then follow up with "the Tory councillor said that...".  This is just because journalists like to avoid using words repeatedly for ease of reading.

Comment: Why has this has been downvoted?  This is a detailed and relevant response to the OP's question, drawing on my personal knowledge as a British political activist.