# Early Modern English: Shakespearean Insult

Tags: early-modern-english, shakespeare

I think many are familiar with the famous line from Shakespeare:

> Shall I compare thee to a summer's day? Thou art more lovely and more
>   temperate.

What I seek to do is keep the analogy but change the second sentence to an insult. I also want to keep the [early-modern-english](/questions/tagged/early-modern-english) style and a few words of the original phrasing so the parody is clear. However, if I use nearly all the original words from the second sentence, it sounds too contrived:

> Shall I compare thee to a summer's day? Nay, thou art much less
>   lovely, let alone temperate.

**Question:** Can someone give me a suitable, slightly less contrived, [early-modern-english](/questions/tagged/early-modern-english) insult using "Thou art more lovely and more temperate" as inspiration?

Comment: "Thou art less lovely and less temperate" might do.  What do you think?

Comment: This question belongs on [writers.se]

Comment: I think you might want to start off with "Shall I compare thee to a winter's day?"; being less lovely and temperate than a winter's day has more bite.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/579/300

Comment: More florid and more balmy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the Washington DC area

> Thou art more humid and more thunderous

or

> Thou art more sweaty and more thunderous

would be appreciated.  It is very humid here in the summer, people sweat a lot, and afternoon thunderstorms are common.

Now, do these words qualify as early modern English insults?

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/humid), **humid** may qualify:

> humid (adj.)
>
> early 15c., from Old French humide, umide "damp, wet" (15c.) or
>   directly from Latin humidus "moist, wet," variant (probably by
>   influence of humus "earth") of umidus, from umere "be moist, be wet,"
>   from Proto-Italic *umo- "wet" (also source of Latin umidus "wet,
>   moist," umiditas "moisture," umor "moisture, fluid," umectus "moist,
>   wet"), perhaps from PIE *uhrmo- "wet," from the same source as Latin
>   urina [de Vaan].

As for **thunderous**, according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=thunderous), it dates from the 1580s, which is Shakespeare's era. (April 1564 (baptised)—23 April 1616).

As for whether these qualify as 16th to 17th century insults, I did not find any quotations in the Oxford English Dictionary that used *humid* and *thunderous* explicitly as insults dating from that era.  However, calling a woman *thunderous* would not have been a compliment; as for humid, I don't know.

**sweaty** is more promising. According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=sweaty) the meaning *soaked with sweat* dates from the 1580s. No woman would want to be called sweaty in any era.

Answer (score 1):

"…. Thou art more sultry and more eccentric," maybe.

(This question is more about writing than ELU, though.)

Comment: *Sultry* is a pun.

Answer (score 1):

**19 Shakespearean Insults We Need To Bring Back** [phactual.com](https://www.phactual.com/19-shakespearean-insults-we-need-to-bring-back/)

As in:

> “Thou art like a toad; ugly and venomous.”